# CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization popup shows and hides immediately

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization popup shows and hides immediately, leaving user no time to press allow button. This is a class I wrote for location managing:

```
import UIKit

class TMLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    static func startLocationManager() {
        let manager = TMLocationManager()
        manager.getPermission()
    }

    private func getPermission () {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager!.delegate = TMLocationManager.init()

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .Denied, .Restricted:
            return
        case .NotDetermined:
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            break
        case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

In my code I just write `TMLocationManager.startLocationManager()`

Comment: You need to retain the `manager` too

Comment: In your startLocationManager function you are creating a local variable which will immediately go out of scope when the function exits.

Comment: Yes that helped @max_ and PotassiumPermanganate 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conjunction with my comment, you need to ensure that the `manager` variable is being retained as it will be released, and the alert dismissed, once the `startLocationManager` method has finished executing.